# Calling a method on object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this method inside a class and when this method is called, its calling a function `validations[dateFormat]()` based on argument `dateFormat`

```
public isValidYearMonthDate(userDateArr: any, dateFormat: string) {
    const dateFormatArr = dateFormat.split('-');
    const validations: any = {
        'YYYY-MM-DD': this.checkYearMonthDate,
        'MM_DD_YYYY': this.checkMonthDateYear,
        'DD_MM_YYYY': this.checkDateMonthYear
    };
    return validations[dateFormat](dateFormatArr, userDateArr);
}
```

Lets say this below function is called, I am getting issue with the `this` keyword. It points to `validations` object at Line 2 `this.isMonthValid` instead of class.

```
private checkYearMonthDate(dateArr: string[], arr: any) {
    return this.isMonthValid(arr[2], arr[1], arr[0]); // LINE 2
}
```

I tried `_this = this` but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I fixed it by using apply:

```
validations[dateFormat].apply(this, [dateFormatArr, userDateArr]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling function with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) like below.

```
return validations[dateFormat].bind(this)(dateFormatArr, userDateArr);
```

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.